# PySpark cast String to DecimalType without rounding in case of unmatching scale

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, casting, bigdecimal

I need to cast numbers from a column with `StringType` to a `DecimalType`. The Decimal type should have a predefined precision and scale, for example, `Decimal(2,1)`. While the numbers in the String column can not fit to this precision and scale.

Here is the example:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("-001.399", )],["String"]).withColumn("Decimal", F.col("String").cast(DecimalType(2,1)))
df.show(truncate=False)

+--------+-------+
|String  |Decimal|
+--------+-------+
|-001.399|-1.4   |
+--------+-------+
```

From the result I see that the number in Decimal format is rounded, which is not a desired behavior in my use case.

**1. Is it possible to cast String to Decimal without rounding?**

The expected result would be:

```
+--------+-------+
|String  |Decimal|
+--------+-------+
|-001.399|-1.3   |
+--------+-------+
```

**2. Is it possible to "strictly" cast String to Decimal so that it will return `null` if the actual scale does not exactly fit to specified scale?**

The expected result would be (like if I would try to cast "-0011.399" to `Decimal(2,1)`):

```
+--------+-------+
|String  |Decimal|
+--------+-------+
|-001.399|null   |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Just to make sure, do you *really* need decimal numbers? Isn't double-precision float enough? I mean, decimals are useful for very large numbers and/or for very big precision. In your case, do you aim for these, or you just want to have a specific number of digits after the decimal separator, but you don't necessarily have big/high-precision numbers?

Comment: FYI - if your data's max precision is, say, 5 -- all decimal values will have the same precision. e.g., `"-01.11"` casted to `decimal(10,5)` becomes `1.11000`

Comment: @ZygD your response answers my question, thanks! Answering your comment - you're right, I need to check if string number has a specific number of digits before and after separator, and then cast it to appropriate numeric type. I don't expect large numbers or scale, but I thought `DecimalType` is a good fit, because you can explicitly specify precision and scale there. Maybe you have a hint how to better implement it?

Comment: The problem which you describe, from the first glance looks a bit different from the one in this question. I don't see where exactly you would need to "cut" a part a number which was the problem in this question. However, if I had your problem, I would first count the digits on both sides. Then, if it's 16, you're good with casting to double. if it's more, go for decimal. Spark's decimal type supports decimal precision up to 38.

Comment: @ZygD, yes, the problem in question is different, because I've already started to move in it's direction, but now due to your hints I will do it in the other way. Thanks a lot for both your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex would only keep 1 digit after the `.` decimal point. You could apply this transformation before casting to decimal type.

```py
F.regexp_extract("String", r"^([^.]*(\.\d)?)", 1)
```

Full test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("-001.399",), ("001.399",), ("-001",), ("001",), ("-001.",), ("001.",), ("-001.39",), ("-001.3",), ("-.39",), (".39",)], ["String"])

df = df.withColumn("String2", F.regexp_extract("String", r"^([^.]*(\.\d)?)", 1))
df = df.withColumn("Decimal", F.col("String2").cast('decimal(2,1)'))

df.show()
# +--------+-------+-------+
# |  String|String2|Decimal|
# +--------+-------+-------+
# |-001.399| -001.3|   -1.3|
# | 001.399|  001.3|    1.3|
# |    -001|   -001|   -1.0|
# |     001|    001|    1.0|
# |   -001.|   -001|   -1.0|
# |    001.|    001|    1.0|
# | -001.39| -001.3|   -1.3|
# |  -001.3| -001.3|   -1.3|
# |    -.39|    -.3|   -0.3|
# |     .39|     .3|    0.3|
# +--------+-------+-------+
```

If you need more digits after the decimal point, you can insert e.g. `{0,3}` into the regex (for up to 3 digits after the decimal point).

```py
r"^([^.]*(\.\d{0,3})?)"
```